# Is there really no way to perform limit() in with() method? (Eloquent)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

`Mode` model has a `hasMany` relationship with `DataSet` model. I want to load data sets with the `with()`-method. It works fine, unless I need a limit on `DataSet` per `Mode`. The following code does not work as expected. It limits the `DataSet` results all together and not individually per `Mode`.

```
$modes = $modes->with(['dataSets' => function ($query) use ($user, $count) {

    // Select data sets of user from each mode

    $query->join('data_set_user', 'id', '=', 'data_set_id')
          ->where('user_id', $user->id);

    if(isset($count))
           $query->limit($count);

 }])->orderBy('order_value')
            ->get();
```

Have a look at the query which this code produces:

```
SELECT * FROM `data_sets` INNER JOIN `data_set_user` on `id` = `data_set_id` where `data_sets`.`mode_id` in (?, ?, ?) and `user_id` = ? limit 5"
```

Is there any Laravel-way to make the limit work for each mode **individually**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible with any Laravel methods.

It's a super hard problem that some SQLs have sufficient methods to tackle it, but others don't.

The problem has been raised multiple times:

- https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/4835
- https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/18014

And most notably (and recently):

- https://github.com/laravel/docs/pull/4918

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look!

Comment: Staudenmeir, a frequent Laravel collaborator and active on SO as well [released a package](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/18014#issuecomment-432643803) that seems to tackle this. I haven't tried it, but you can look into that